# BannerAd variable has not initialized error

Tags: flutter, dart

i get an error that my BannerAd variable is not initialized and my app crash, so i move my _banner in top of code and still not work, i move it inside the state class and still not initialized what should need to do to be initialized ?

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late BannerAd _banner;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies(){
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final adState = context.read(adStateProvider);
    adState.initialization.then((value)
    {
      setState(() {
        _banner = BannerAd(size: AdSize.banner, adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUniteId, listener: adState.adListener, request: AdRequest())..load();
      });
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(

      body: Center(
        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('pub'),
          if(_banner == null)Text('null hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh')
      else Expanded(child: AdWidget(ad: _banner),),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your widget builds before `_banner` is initialized, even if you initialized it in `initState`, will still not work, because you initialize it after a future completes, and that future completes after the build method got executed. so the solution here is to remove the `late` keyword before `BannerAd` and also make it nullable. like this:

```
// this doesn't give you any initialization errors 
// because _banner will have a default value of null
BannerAd? _banner;
```

now you will have a different problem, because `AdWidget` takes a non-null object, you need to assert that `_banner` is not null with null assertion operator `!`, like this:

```
AdWidget(ad: _banner!)
```

this way it's like you're telling the compiler that "I'm sure that _banner is not null", because you only build this widget if `_banner` is not null because of the `if else` clause

Note that when using `!`, you have to be completely sure that the object will actually be not null then, if it's null, it will throw a null assertion exception.

you can read and practice on null safety with this [dart codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety)

Comment: i get this error in this line: AdWidget(ad: _banner), The argument type 'BannerAd?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AdWithView'.

Comment: that's because `AdWithView` is a non-null parameter, and you're passing to it a nullable object, you can fix this by adding a null assertion with `!` like this, `AdWidget(ad: _banner!)`. i updated the answer too